# Debugging Java program for changing timezone configuration file on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, java, timezone

Here is a ruby script I wrote to change the timezone configuration on Ubuntu. I run it with **jruby** (a Ruby interpreter running in a JVM).

```
require 'java'

if ARGV.length == 0
  puts "Usage: jruby change_timezone.rb America/Toronto"
  exit
end

old_zone = File.read("../../../etc/timezone")
puts old_zone
time1 = Time.now
puts "Current Time:"+time1.localtime.to_s

new_zone = ARGV[0]
open('../../../etc/timezone','w') do |f|
  f.puts new_zone.to_s
  f.close
end

new_zone = File.read("../../../etc/timezone")
puts new_zone
time2 = Time.now
puts "Updated Time:"+time2.localtime.to_s
```

It does change the configuration file properly. However, the output for the script is not as expected.

Assume the default value for the timezone is `America/Toronto`.
When I run the command `jruby change_timezone.rb Asia/Chongqing`, the output is:

```
America/Toronto
Current Time:Thu Jul 07 14:43:23 -0400 2011
Asia/Chongqing
Updated Time:Thu Jul 07 14:43:23 -0400 2011 (My Note: +0800 expected!!!)
```

Continuing with the command `jruby change_timezone.rb Europe/Amsterdam`, I end up with the following:

```
Asia/Chongqing
Current Time:Fri Jul 08 03:18:25 +0800 2011 (My Note: it actually got updated from last run!!!)
Europe/Amsterdam
Updated Time:Fri Jul 08 03:18:25 +0800 2011 (My Note: +0200 expected!!!)
```

Going further with `jruby change_timezone.rb Europe/Amsterdam` again, I get the following:

```
Europe/Amsterdam
Current Time:Thu Jul 07 21:21:27 +0200 2011
Europe/Amsterdam
Updated Time:Thu Jul 07 21:21:27 +0200 2011
```

Can someone figure out why it didn't work as expected?

Comment: Just a note: why are you using relative paths?

Comment: @pbm Good point. Absolute paths can make code more portable. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Gilles As you can see from the output, the time did change while I didn't touch /etc/localtime. What confuses me here is that the time change wouldn't show upon the first run(it showed on the following run!!).

Comment: @TerryLee The process reads the timezone the first time it needs it, and doesn't check for changes afterwards. What surprises me is that you're seeing a change without modifying `/etc/localtime`. Do you see the same effect with plain `ruby`? Please post the output of `ls -l /etc/localtime` and `strace -efile jruby change_timezone.rb Asia/Chongqing`.

Comment: @Gilles It seems that /etc/localtime won't change between runs. Plus, with plain Ruby I'm not able to see the change. I figure that Time.now results in different objects(java Time vs ruby Time) with jruby vs plain ruby.

Comment: @Terry Which JVM are you using (Sun/Oracle, OpenJDK, gcj, …)? It seems to be peculiar in using `/etc/timezone` instead of `/etc/localtime`.

Comment: @Gilles I'm using Sun/Oracle.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is an issue in how Java determines the time zone under unix systems.

The [POSIX specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/tzset.html) does not specify how to determine the timezone when the `TZ` environment variable is not set. I can't find anything in the [Linux Standard Base](http://refspecs.freestandards.org/) about this.
The [base system library (GNU libc)](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/TZ-Variable.html#index-g_t_002fetc_002flocaltime-2669) uses `/etc/localtime` to determine the timezone. So on non-embedded Linux, `/etc/localtime` is where the timezone information is stored, and ideally the story would end here.

<sub>(Looking around: FreeBSD, NetBSD and OpenBSD use `/etc/localtime`. Solaris and a few others use `/etc/TIMEZONE`. The [Rosetta Stone for Unix](http://bhami.com/rosetta.html) shows what other unices use. [Dietlibc](http://www.fefe.de/dietlibc/oldnews.html) (used in some embedded Linux systems) uses `/etc/localtime`, while [uClibc](http://www.uclibc.org/FAQ.html#timezones) uses `/etc/TZ` (unless [patched](http://lists.uclibc.org/pipermail/uclibc/2010-April/043959.html)).)</sub>

Unfortunately, Java does things differently. Debian and Ubuntu have a file called `/etc/timezone` which contains the name of the timezone. This extra file is intended for the packaging system, so that it remembers a geographical name like `Europe/Amsterdam` rather than just the description of the timezone (offsets over time, and display names `CET`, `CEST` and `CEDT`). This is both friendlier to humans and robust in case the geographical locale updates its time zone rules. Sun (now Oracle) Java prefers `/etc/timezone` (or `/etc/sysconfig/clock` on Red Hat-based distributions) [see bug #6456628](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6456628) to `/etc/localtime`, and OpenJDK and [gcj](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=28550) follow suit.

See also: [How do I find the current system timezone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3118582/how-do-i-find-the-current-system-timezone); [Java Time Zone is messed up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6392/java-time-zone-is-messed-up).

The solution is simple: always update `/etc/timezone` and `/etc/localtime` together. On Debian or Ubuntu, [the official method to change the timezone is `dpkg-reconfigure tzdata`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16190/how-to-make-an-ubuntu-time-zone-change-stick). To change the timezone only for one application, set the `TZ` environment variable (this is portable across all unix systems).

Comment: This works. All I needed to do was running `sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata`. After restarting the Java server it picked up the correct timezone. According to [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/additional-recommended-steps-for-new-ubuntu-14-04-servers), you should also run `sudo apt-get install ntp` to enable NTP Synchronization.