# Russian timezone is not up-to-date

Tags: linux, timezone

I have noticed, that the Russian timezone is not up-to-date. The GMT offset is set to +3 h now, whereas the current GMT offset is  +4 hours.
Could someone tell me how can i manually edit the tzdata file to set it up to date?

Answer (score 2):

The timezone data resides in `/usr/share/zoneinfo`, but the format is binary and hard to edit. You could try installing the current version of the [tzinfo database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database).

Answer (score 2):

You should perform all updates for your distribution. Every operating system out there repacks the [collaborative zoneinfo database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database), and they usually push updates when laws change.

If your distribution doesn't have an update, you can't edit the files as installed, but you can recompile just this file. Download the latest archive, extract the file for your timezone, and run `zic` (if your timezone is `Europe/Moscow`, which it sounds like from your description):

```
mkdir tmp
cd tmp
tar xzf tzdata2011n.tar.gz europe
zic -d . europe                      # or /usr/sbin/zic if zic isn't in your $PATH
```

Copy or link the file `Europe/Moscow` as `/etc/localtime`. With programs using GNU libc (i.e. almost all programs on a non-embedded Linux system), that's all you need to do. For Java programs, this is not enough; see [Debugging Java program for changing timezone configuration file on Ubuntu](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16241/debugging-java-program-for-changing-timezone-configuration-file-on-ubuntu). Your best bet is to copy the new version of `Europe/Moscow` over the existing one in `/usr/share/zoneinfo`.