# What else apart from /etc/localtime and $TZ affects `date`?

Tags: date, timezone

I have a fedora 20 installation with the clock set to UTC, and no `TZ` environment variable. Why the `date` command is outputting the date in the `CET` timezone (which by the way is my local timezone)?

```
[fedora@slave2 ~]$ ls -l /etc/localtime
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 27 Apr  8  2014 /etc/localtime -> /usr/share/zoneinfo/Etc/UTC
[fedora@slave2 ~]$ echo $TZ

[fedora@slave2 ~]$ env | grep TZ
[fedora@slave2 ~]$ date
Wed Mar 18 17:20:44 CET 2015
```

Also, asking for the time in a little java program outputs the time in UTC (while if I set the TZ environment to CET, then in outputs the date in CET):

```
[fedora@slave2 ~]$ java DateDemo
Wed Mar 18 16:24:17 UTC 2015
[fedora@slave2 ~]$ TZ=CET java DateDemo
Wed Mar 18 17:24:24 CET 2015
```

(I got the `DateDemo` java code from http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_date_time.htm)

Additional info:

```
[fedora@slave2 ~]$ type date
date is hashed (/usr/bin/date)
[fedora@slave2 ~]$ set +h
[fedora@slave2 ~]$ type date
date is /usr/bin/date
[fedora@slave2 ~]$ date
Wed Mar 18 17:58:26 CET 2015
[fedora@slave2 ~]$ strace -fe open date
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/etc/localtime", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
Wed Mar 18 18:02:41 CET 2015
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

zdump:

```
[fedora@slave2 ~]$ zdump -v /etc/localtime | head
/etc/localtime  -9223372036854775808 = NULL
/etc/localtime  -9223372036854689408 = NULL
/etc/localtime  Mon Dec 31 23:53:55 1900 UTC = Mon Dec 31 23:59:59 1900 LMT isdst=0 gmtoff=364
/etc/localtime  Mon Dec 31 23:53:56 1900 UTC = Mon Dec 31 23:53:56 1900 WET isdst=0 gmtoff=0
/etc/localtime  Sun Sep 29 23:59:59 1946 UTC = Sun Sep 29 23:59:59 1946 WET isdst=0 gmtoff=0
/etc/localtime  Mon Sep 30 00:00:00 1946 UTC = Mon Sep 30 01:00:00 1946 CET isdst=0 gmtoff=3600
/etc/localtime  Sun Mar 31 00:59:59 1985 UTC = Sun Mar 31 01:59:59 1985 CET isdst=0 gmtoff=3600
/etc/localtime  Sun Mar 31 01:00:00 1985 UTC = Sun Mar 31 03:00:00 1985 CEST isdst=1 gmtoff=7200
/etc/localtime  Sun Sep 29 00:59:59 1985 UTC = Sun Sep 29 02:59:59 1985 CEST isdst=1 gmtoff=7200
/etc/localtime  Sun Sep 29 01:00:00 1985 UTC = Sun Sep 29 02:00:00 1985 CET isdst=0 gmtoff=3600
```

Comment: What does `type date` return? Could it possibly be aliased? What about `strace -fe open date`?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas updated with more info

Comment: How about `zdump -v /etc/localtime `?

Comment: I'd bet someone/something did a `cp some-CET-timezone /etc/localtime` overriding `/usr/share/zoneinfo/Etc/UTC`

Comment: I agree.  This doesn't affect the Java code because Java has its own TZ libraries.

Comment: It seems you were right, someone tried to overwrite /etc/localtime without realizing it was a symlink, so it overwrote the UTC zonefile instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `date` command, like almost all programs, relies on the standard library to access timezone data. On Linux (except for some embedded systems) and *BSD, the standard library determines the current timezone from the content of `/etc/localtime`.

It appears that on your system, `/etc/localtime` does not contain what it seems to contain. Like [Stéphane Chazelas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/191017/what-else-apart-from-etc-localtime-and-tz-affects-date#comment319428_191017) and [derobert](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/191017/what-else-apart-from-etc-localtime-and-tz-affects-date#comment319351_191017), I strongly suspect that the file `/usr/share/zoneinfo/Etc/UTC`, which `/etc/localtime` is a symbolic link to, contains incorrect information, probably because someone who didn't know what they were doing attempted to change the system timezone and ended up overwriting a system file.

I recommend reinstalling the time zone information to make sure that your system isn't corrupted. Run `rpm -qf /usr/share/zoneinfo/Etc/UTC` to see which package contains that file and reinstall it with `yum reinstall`. Then set the timezone properly, either with the [`timedatectl` command](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/21/html/System_Administrators_Guide/ch-Configuring_the_Date_and_Time.html) or by changing the `/etc/localtime` symbolic link and the text file `/etc/zoneinfo` or `/etc/sysconfig/clock` (I think Fedora uses the latter):

```
ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Madrid /etc/localtime
echo Europe/Madrid >/etc/zoneinfo
sed -i -e '/^ *ZONE=/d' /etc/sysconfig/clock
echo 'ZONE="Europe/Madrid"' >>/etc/sysconfig/clock
```

[Java does things differently](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16241/debugging-java-program-for-changing-timezone-configuration-file-on-ubuntu) — it bypasses the standard library and reads `/etc/timezone` or `/etc/sysconfig/clock` instead. That's why you're seeing different timezone information from Java programs.

Comment: Totally right, the file belongs to the package `tzdata` and `rpm -V tzdata` shows that the UTC zone files have been modified. After reinstalling`tzdata` everything works as expected.

Answer (score 3):

why don't you use zdump to see whats going on with that zoneinfo file.  Maybe it has really been replaced as some have suggested:

```
# zdump /usr/share/zoneinfo/Etc/UTC
/usr/share/zoneinfo/Etc/UTC  Thu Mar 19 01:14:47 2015 UTC
```

If it displays CET instead then you know somebody replaced the file.

Answer (score -1):

/etc/sysconfig/clock file may be having an impact.