# command line tool to set time zone

Tags: command-line, centos, configuration

In Centos 5.x there is the text mode interface of system-config-date to set the time zone. Although that utility still exists in Centos 6 the text mode is gone. Is there anything similar in Centos 6?

Answer (score 4):

`/etc/localtime` controls the system timezone.  It's just a symlink to one of the timezone files in `/usr/share/zoneinfo`.

```
ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/your/zone /etc/localtime
```

Comment: That's what i had already done. It is not what I asked for.

Comment: I think this is the right answer, but @Clodoaldo your question may actually how to make the change ACTIVE without rebooting. Changing the file only affects future environments, the stuff that is already running already thinks it knows what time it is. See this question for related issues: [How to make an Ubuntu time zone change stick?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/16190)

Comment: @Caleg _"I think this is the right answer"_ It is not. That answer is all around the net and it is an answer for another question. _"your question may actually how"_ No, my question is exactly what was stated. If you think the information you posted is important, and I think it is, create your own question and answer it yourself. You will earn points for that.