# Configure localtime. dpkg-reconfigure tzdata

Tags: debian, scripting, timezone

I'm using this to configure localtime:

```
dpkg-reconfigure tzdata
```

It is ncurses interface. I'm looking for the way to programming this. Is there true way without user ncurses interface?

How to change localtime by one shell command?

Comment: This question has an [up-to-date answer on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/84521/automate-dpkg-reconfigure-tzdata/846989#846989).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to change the timezone by one shell command.

Do you have `timedatectl` on your system?

If so:

`timedatectl status` will show your current settings.

`timedatectl list-timezones` shows available timezones.

`timedatectl set-timezone Antarctica/Mawson` sets it.

**Note:** If the RTC is configured to be in the local time, this will also update the RTC time.

Comment: Where's `timedatectl` from? `apt-file search timedatectl` returns nothing on Debian stable.

Comment: `timedatectl` is available from the `systemd-services` package on Ubuntu and from `systemd` on Fedora

Comment: Hmm. `Failed to create bus connection: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 7):

> Is there true way without user ncurses interface?

```
echo Antarctica/Mawson >/etc/timezone
dpkg-reconfigure -f noninteractive tzdata
```

Yes, you can create one shell command:

```
sh -c 'echo Antarctica/Mawson >/etc/timezone && dpkg-reconfigure -f noninteractive tzdata'
```

:)

There is a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tzdata/+bug/772024) in `tzdata`: certain values get normalized by `dpkg-reconfigure`:

```
echo 'US/Central' >/etc/timezone
dpkg-reconfigure -f noninteractive tzdata
# Current default time zone: 'America/Chicago'

echo 'US/Eastern' >/etc/timezone
apt-get install --reinstall tzdata
# Current default time zone: 'America/New_York'
```

Comment: In 16.04 you have to set `/etc/localtime`, `dpkg-reconfigure` then updates `/etc/timezone`: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tzdata/+bug/1554806

Comment: this one works under docker, timedatectl does not.

Comment: I upvote this because the `apt install --reinstall tzdata` fixed my date problems.  Even after adjusting `/etc/localtime` and `/etc/timezone` either by hand or using the various `tz*` commands (including `dpkg-reconfigure`) left the date in a weird state (showed as local time being the same as UTC but timezone was "America" not "PDT")

Comment: I also had to do `/etc/init.d/cron restart` in order for cron jobs to start running under the new timezone.

Answer (score 2):

The way that I'm taking everytime:

```
# /bin/ln -fs /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Novosibirsk /etc/localtime
```

It working pretty everywhere, from Linux to BSD family.

Comment: `dpkg-reconfigure tzdata` updates `/etc/timezone`. `openjdk` uses `/etc/timezone` before `/etc/localtime` to guess the local timezone. see [The algorithm that OpenJDK uses to guess the local timezone ID on Linux](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/core-libs-dev/2013-August/020229.html).

Comment: see also: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/16294/120177

Comment: `cron` [uses](http://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/pkg-cron/pkg-cron.git/tree/debian/cron.init#n56) `/etc/timezone` for `TZ` setting.

Comment: On Debian `dpkg-reconfigure` makes copy, `timedatectl` makes copy. See [timedated doesn't support split-usr, uses a symlink for /etc/localtime](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=726256), [Useless systemd-timedated /etc/localtime symlink complain in syslog](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1409594)

Answer (score 2):

None of the answers here worked for me. What worked for me was running:

```
printf "%s\n"                                              \
       "tzdata  tzdata/Areas    select America"            \
       "tzdata  tzdata/Zones/America    select New_York"   \
       | debconf-set-selections
```

After doing this, when you can now trigger

```
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y tzdata
```

and it will automatically use the correct time zone based on the pre-loaded settings.

Answer (score 2):

When you have interactive commands it's always an option to use `expect` program:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set timeout 360
spawn dpkg-reconfigure tzdata

expect "Geographic area:"

send -- "2\r"

expect "city or region"

send -- "134\r"
```

This will look for the string in stdout "expect" and then send the string in "send" to stdin.

Comment: It's worth noting that if your app doesn't use stdout/stdin then this solution won't help.  However in the OPs actual use case this should do.